# XText: split tokens on brackets

Tags: xtext

I use XText with a grammer like this:

```
Element: element '[' name=ID ']' '{' content+=Content+ '}'
Content: STRING
```

Now, the following is valid:

```
element[blub] { "Text" }
```

but this is not:

```
element[blub]{ "Text" }
```

Error: `mismatched input: ']{' expecting ']'`.

How can I tell the lexer to split the `']{'` in two tokens?

I already tried

```
terminal BRACKET: '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}'
```

and `hiding (WS, …, BRACKET)`, but this did not work.

Comment: Please post the complete grammar snippet. I would expect that you used ']{' as a keyword somewhere. The terminal BRACKET is not necessary.

Comment: I have run into a basically identical issue with ')]' except in my grammar i do have it as `')'']'` but i still get the same error. Yes workflow has been run and projects refreshed multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates that you used a keyword ']{' somewhere in your grammar. It can be resolved by refactoring that into two keywords ']' '{'.